# Custom font in a Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I know you can customize fonts by using Interface Builder and selecting a font.  However, I'm curious if I can use a custom font that's not included by default on systems.  Is there a way to include a custom font in my application?

Comment: @poke: This is not a duplicate, this is for **Mac**, as clearly outlined in my tags.  Please read more carefully.

Comment: @poke:  It's alright. :)

Comment: Guess this would be the better possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444717/embed-font-in-a-mac-bundle – can't change my close vote now though :/

Comment: @poke: That looks perfect.  I hadn't seen that even though I searched for it. :)  On a side note, would it be even legal for me to try to embed Calibri in my application?

Comment: It's unlikely, being a MS font. You should check the license agreement.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

While the manual font activation procedure is one option, you might also consider the `ATSApplicationFontsPath` Info.plist key:

[Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/GeneralPurposeKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009253-SW8):

> "`ATSApplicationFontsPath` (`String` - Mac
>   OS X) identifies the location of a
>   font file or directory of fonts in the
>   bundle’s `Resources` directory. If
>   present, Mac OS X activates the fonts
>   at the specified path for use by the
>   bundled application. The fonts are
>   activated only for the bundled
>   application and not for the system as
>   a whole. The path itself should be
>   specified as a relative directory of
>   the bundle’s Resources directory. For
>   example, if a directory of fonts was
>   at the path
>   `/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Stuff/MyFonts/`,
>   you should specify the string
>   `Stuff/MyFonts/` for the value of this
>   key."

I'd be sure to double-check, but I believe this functionality was added in OS X 10.5.x (which the code posted by Jinhyung Park targets).

Comment: Yeah or you can use Core Text which was introduced in Snow Leopard, I believe.

Comment: This solution is the right way to go. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't mark this as answer before, but there you go. :)

Comment: Could you please help me for same issue, [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279279/unable-to-add-a-custom-font-in-mac-app-osx-10-9-xcode5)

Answer (score 4):

ATSApplicationFontsPath uses [NSBundle mainbundle] path as base path, so it does not work when Resources folder is not located there (e.g. for app plugins).

In my Cocoa plugin I need to load custom fonts using CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

static void FGDActivateFont(NSString *fontName)
{

    // Can't make ATSApplicationFontsPath in Info.plist work for plugins (non-standard Resources path)

    NSArray *availableFonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFonts];

    if (![availableFonts containsObject:fontName]) {

        NSURL *fontURL = [[FGDRapidCart bundle] URLForResource:fontName withExtension:@"ttf" subdirectory:@"Fonts"];
        assert(fontURL);
        CFErrorRef error = NULL;
        if (!CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fontURL, kCTFontManagerScopeProcess, &error))
        {
            CFShow(error);
        }

    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        FGDActivateFont(@“FontAwesome”);
    }
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/OneSadCookie/Extendaword/blob/master/Extendaword/main.m

Comment: Good answer, needed this for my screensaver, plist values wouldn't work there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example for Mac App custom font loading.

```
NSString *fontFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/fonts"];
fontsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fontFilePath];
if(fontsURL != nil)
{
    OSStatus status;
    FSRef fsRef;
    CFURLGetFSRef((CFURLRef)fontsURL, &fsRef);
    status = ATSFontActivateFromFileReference(&fsRef, kATSFontContextLocal, kATSFontFormatUnspecified, 
                                              NULL, kATSOptionFlagsDefault, NULL);
    if (status != noErr)
    {
        errorMessage = @"Failed to acivate fonts!";
        goto error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call `[NSFont fontWithName:@"fontname"]`?

Comment: I read the discussion at http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?UsingCustomFontsInYourCocoaApplications. After loading your fonts, you can use [NSFont fontWithName:@""]. I just checked in my Mac OS X application again that it is working.

Comment: Funny you don't find anything in either Xcode help or ADC when searching for ATSFontActivateFromFileReference - need to go to "ATS/ATSFont.h" on your hard disk for any info..

Comment: ATSFontActivateFromFileReference = Undocumented = App Store Rejection

Comment: @Tibidabo several years late, but not undocumented at all: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ATS_Concepts/ManagingFonts.pdf

Answer (score -7):

I have managed to do this using cocos2d (CCLabelBMFont) and hiero tool. You will need to create the font using the hiero, and give this font to the CCLabelBMFont object.

Comment: My question is about the **Mac**, not about the iPhone.