# Unable to add a custom font in Mac app (OSX 10.9+ Xcode5+)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfont

I have gone through these SO posts:

[Embed font in a mac bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444717/embed-font-in-a-mac-bundle?lq=1)

[Custom font in a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283572/custom-font-in-a-cocoa-application)

I tried exactly same (rechecked multiple times), but I am not able to add a custom font to my Mac App.

All details are shown in attached pictures.

Plist is updated: (Tried Fonts and Fonts/ both)
[image]
In App Bundle it's there in Fonts folder path:
[image]

But my code is unable to find and read the font :
[image]

Any help / pointing out my mistake is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is 'PlanerReg' the font name or just the file name?

Comment: @Aderstedt: Thanks for your comment, it helped me to figure out the issue.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I have successfully implemented the font in my app but if the font is not installed on user's mac then is it possible to check if the font is installed or not or automatically we can install the font from mac app?

Comment: @Manthan: Why don't you ship the font with the bundle resource and load the font there? If you want to install your font in the OS itself, then its other story.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I have one query regrading sandboxing my app... Can you please guide me???

Comment: @Manthan: yes go ahead, if I can help you

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Hi, you there???

Comment: Hi , I have the same issue. I have add some font file(ttf). And register the font in the info.plist file. I use [NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFonts] to enum the font but cannot find my custom font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment `Is 'PlanerReg' the font name or just the file name?`

This helped me out to figure the issue.

Actually the font file name is `PlanerReg`, but the actual font name is `Planer`.

Now its working.