# Embedding font in cocoa App and use it by IB

Tags: cocoa

My OSX app uses `Helvetica` and `MyriadPro` for some textfields, i get that some users disable these fonts by font book and consecutively they are replaced by system fonts...

I read other questions here in stackoverflow based on embedding file etc in Cocoa application, but i need something slightly different. 
I want to setup my textfield with Interface Builder as usual (i haven't text field created with `[NSFont fontWithName:@""]`) and define my textfields font by IB, than embed fonts in some way... is this a good solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have configured a text field to use a particular font in Interface Builder and the  font is available on the user's system, then it will be used.

It doesn't matter how the font is loaded. If the font is either active in their system or embedded in your app then it will be used.

You should use the method I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444717/embed-font-in-a-mac-bundle/2444772#2444772) for embedding a font in your app bundle. Make sure you have permission to distribute the font, you definitely do *not* have permission to distribute Helvetica or Myriad Pro unless you have specifically licensed those fonts.