# fontWithName:size: How to import own font to project?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uifont, custom-font

I try to import my own font to a project and i'm stuck. I do my research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)
but **As of iOS 3.2, this functionality is built in. If you need to support pre-3.2, you can still use this solution.** and I create app for iOS 5.0.

I'm try to use `fontWithName:size:` and [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) said that **The fully specified name of the font. This name incorporates both the font family name and the specific style information for the font.** So I Put there my display name.

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation-Light" size:10.0];
```

But it doesn't work. Where do i have store this font? In my project? is that correct name? My font name is: `Sansation_Light.ttf`

Comment: please edit your question to indicate how you are including your ttf file within your project and how does it arrive in your application bundle?

Comment: Now in plist, problem solved!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: If you read my question you will notice that i already menioned this thread in my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed font in a mac bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444717/embed-font-in-a-mac-bundle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!
http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635

Comment: And this is why we post the answers in SO, not just links to websites.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For This,

```
  You have to add  key   "Fonts provided by application" in your info.plist .   
  for that key add  your ttf file name  for ex: "Sansation_Light.ttf" .
  it works fine for me.
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be the line between Sansation and Light, it should be

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation_Light" size:10.0];
```

Or change your font name to Sansation-Light.ttf

Comment: Even if he changed the file name, doesn't `-fontWithName:size:` use the font's *internal* name?