# Custom fonts in Interface Builder XCode 6

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, xcode6.3

I want to use custom Fonts in a mac desktop application. I am using XCode 6.
is there any way after including custom fonts (.ttf files) in the resources folder and making necessary changes in info.plist file that these fonts will show up in IB? I know that there is something in iOS but I am looking for Mac OS X desktop applications

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the font in your app doesn't make it available in the storyboard/xib editor. You must install the font for system use to make it available in Interface Builder. The easiest way to do that is to drag the font files onto the Font Book app.  Then you can choose the font in the font picker for your text field or label or whatever.

If you also want to embed the font in your app, you need to add Copy Files phase to your target to copy the font files into a subdirectory of your app's Resources directory, and set that path as the value of the `ATSApplicationFontsPath` key in your app's `Info.plist`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444772/77567) explains the process in more detail.